# Spring Security class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter doesn't register

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring project, the web security class is not getting picked up. Specifically a user should need to be authenticated for any url except "/login" and "/logout", but they are let through. Here's my web security class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
    System.out.println("This line doesn't print.");
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
}
```

Here's the rest of my project if that's useful:

https://github.com/ScorchConway/Dog-Park---Spring

Comment: why do you have @EnableWebSecurity annotation both here and in com/example/dp/dogpark/DogparkApplication.java ?

Comment: I tried all sorts of things to get that class to register, including putting @EnableWebSecurity in both classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WebSecurityConfig.java is in another package than DogparkAplication.java (probably a typo)

/com/example/dp/**dopark**/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

vs

/com/example/dp/**dogpark**/DogparkApplication.java

You have `@SpringBootApplication` in DogparkApplication.java, so by default component scan will check only its package and subpackages ( /com/example/dp/**dogpark**/* ).

Comment: Oh jeez, I thought it would probably come down to a silly typo...
That worked. Thanks for your help.